# ForEach loop not producing the desired result

Tags: loops, powershell, logfile

I have written a script to Identify a timestamp in a logfile:

```
    $start = Get-Content "C:\Webserverlogfiles\ise*.log" | select -first 1 -skip 6 


$end -match  '(([0-9][0-9]:){2}([0-9][0-9]))'
$end = $Matches[1]
$start -match  '(([0-9][0-9]:){2}([0-9][0-9]))' 
$start = $Matches[1]

$TimeDiff = New-TimeSpan $end $start


if ($TimeDiff.Seconds -lt 0) {
    $Hrs = ($TimeDiff.Hours) + 23
    $Mins = ($TimeDiff.Minutes) + 59
    $Secs = ($TimeDiff.Seconds) + 59 }
else {
    $Hrs = $TimeDiff.Hours
    $Mins = $TimeDiff.Minutes
    $Secs = $TimeDiff.Seconds }
$refreshrate = '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f $Hrs,$Mins,$Secs


echo $refreshrate
```

This returns the result I am after which is the timespan between each refresh.

Now I am trying to expand on this so it loops through the whole file. And so far my script just hangs.

```
    $Workfrom = Get-Content "C:\Webserverlogfiles\ise*.log"

    Foreach ($Line in (Get-Content $Workfrom)) {

        $end = $line | Select-String 'ShowStatus = Reset Status' -SimpleMatch
        $end -match '(([0-9][0-9]:){2}([0-9][0-9]))'
        $end = $Matches[1]

        $start = $line | Select-String 'ShowStatus = Waiting for server ()' -SimpleMatch
        $start -match '(([0-9][0-9]:){2}([0-9][0-9]))'
        $start = $matches[1]

        $TimeDiff = New-TimeSpan $end $start       

        if ($TimeDiff.Seconds -lt 0) {
            $Hrs = ($TimeDiff.Hours) + 23
            $Mins = ($TimeDiff.Minutes) + 59
            $Secs = ($TimeDiff.Seconds) + 59 }
        else {
            $Hrs = $TimeDiff.Hours
            $Mins = $TimeDiff.Minutes
            $Secs = $TimeDiff.Seconds }

    $refreshrate = '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f $Hrs,$Mins,$Secs


    echo $refreshrate

    }
```

From what I can tell this is correct unless I have grouped too much into the ForEach loop. Can I ask what I am missing?

Comment: try changing your second get-content to:
` Foreach ($Line in $Workfrom)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$Workfrom = Get-Content "C:\Webserverlogfiles\ise*.log"

Foreach ($Line in (Get-Content $Workfrom)
```

to

```
$Workfrom = Get-Content "C:\Webserverlogfiles\ise*.log"

Foreach ($Line in $Workfrom) {
```

`$workfrom` is already the lines of text. Otherwise, perhaps you meant `Get-ChildItem` in the first line?

Comment: maybe I did. Does Child-Item grab the Line in the text whereas Get-Content loads the whole text?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` gets file statistics (name, creationtime, size, path lastwritetime). `Get-Content` gets the data from inside the file. When you `get-content ise*.log` it loads text from all the files matching that name pattern. Then you try to `get-content` again and it tries to load content from files called `[2016-10-31 12:01] 200 GET / HTTP/1.1` or whatever the log lines are, and finds nothing. So the loop will never run. (But I'm surprised it doesn't output lots of file not found errors).

Comment: Thank You everyone. Much better understanding of what is going on now. I now presume it "Hangs" because the file is so large that it ends up searching and searching whereas if something was found it should echo the result :) Thank you again!